# Android Studio: Google Admob Interstitial test ad works only partially

Tags: firebase, admob, interstitial

I have a problem while using the test Interstitial ad from Google Admob on my virtual devices. It is working only partially. It works fine on my virtual devices Nexus S (API 21), Nexus 9 (API 29) and Pixel 2 (API 30), but not for Nexus 6 (API 22) and Nexus 9 (API 22).
I have also deimplemented and implemented the 2 not working virtual devices, but they are still not working and I got the following message:
"W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date"

```html
"W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
    The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date"
```

What can be the reason for that? Do I need also Firebase implementation in my dependencies and if yes why only for a few virtual devices / APIs?

See my Gradle coding below:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.riskbattlehelper"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
}
```

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```